# Custom Outlook notification bar in email view

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Is it possible to programmatically add an alert/notification bar to email view in Outlook 2016?

I checked the VSTO and I could not figure it out if it is possible to add something like the following internal notification bar with Context Menu.

[image: outlook notification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider creating an adjoining Outlook form region for displaying your data/information to a user. See [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions) for more information.

Add-in Express provides a layout for displaying your form region at the top of the inspector window (under the ribbon). Read more about possible layouts on the [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) page.

Answer (score 0):

No. The best you can do is add a category to the item - it will be displayed in that general area.

Comment: Is it possible to add a clickable link to category or a context Menu?

Comment: No. There is no way to do that.